# Implementation for Iterator<List<String>> doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, unit-testing, iterator, implementation

I have to write an implementation for Iterator interface.

Its constructor should look like following:

```
public BlockIterator(Iterator<List<String>> iterator, String regex) {
```

To make a long story short, this implementation should parse files with huge sizes, thus can't save it to memory (like storing and processing to array or collection), everything should be operated "on the fly".

Also, `next()` implementation should return sublist from the first occurrence of pattern to next one. However, next one shouldn't be included.

One more notice, `hasNext()` should be idempotent. Even after 20 calls, the result should be the same.

Here is my solution with tests:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

class BlockIterator implements Iterator<List<String>> {

    private final Iterator<List<String>> iterator;
    private final Pattern pattern;

    public BlockIterator(Iterator<List<String>> iterator, String regex) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> line = iterator.next();
            for (String word : line) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> next() {
        String matchWord = null;
        List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> line = iterator.next();
            for (String word : line) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    if (null != matchWord) {
                        return result;
                    } else {
                        matchWord = word;
                    }
                }
                if (null != matchWord) {
                    result.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class BlockIteratorTest {

    public static final List<List<String>> lines = Lists.newArrayList(
            Lists.newArrayList("123"),
            Lists.newArrayList("- test -"),
            Lists.newArrayList("start"),
            Lists.newArrayList("end"),
            Lists.newArrayList("test123"));

    @Test
    public void testNext() throws Exception {
        List<String> expectedFirstNext = Lists.newArrayList("- test -", "start", "end");
        List<String> expectedSecondNext = Lists.newArrayList("test123");

        BlockIterator blockIterator = new BlockIterator(lines.iterator(), "test");

        List<String> actualFirstNext = blockIterator.next();
        assertEquals(expectedFirstNext, actualFirstNext);

        List<String> actualSecondNext = blockIterator.next();
        assertEquals(expectedSecondNext, actualSecondNext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHasNext() throws Exception {
        BlockIterator blockIterator = new BlockIterator(lines.iterator(), "test");

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            assertTrue(blockIterator.hasNext());
        }
    }
}
```

It has few fails:

- `hasNext()` isn't idempotent
- after second `next()` call we should return only match subllist (because no text anymore).

I couldn't find an effective solution in such case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Once you call `iterator.hasNext()` you are changing the state of your `iterator` and wont be able to reuse it in both `hashNext` and `next` methods. Maybe you need to take `Iterable< List<String> >` and create a new Iterator in your `hasNext` and `next` calls.

Comment: @tsolakp I can't change the condition of implementation. Somehow have to use existing options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried playing with this, not sure if this is what you mean, but it's passing your tests, so... it's something! I don't understand your second fail and I'm not sure what you want to happen when the inner lists have more than 1 word, but try this anyway:

```java
class IteratorTesting implements Iterator<List<String>> {

    private final Iterator<List<String>> iterator;
    private final Pattern pattern;

    private boolean hasNext = false;
    private List<String> next = null;
    private String startNext = null;

    public IteratorTesting(Iterator<List<String>> iterator, String regex) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        hasNext = checkNext();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    private boolean checkNext() {
        String matchWord = null;
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(startNext != null)
            result.add(startNext);

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> line = iterator.next();
            for(String word : line) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
                if(matcher.find()) {
                    if(null != matchWord || startNext != null) {
                        next = result;
                        startNext = word;
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        matchWord = word;
                    }
                }
                if(null != matchWord || startNext != null) {
                    result.add(word);
                }
            }
        }
        next = result;
        startNext = null;
        return !next.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> next() {
        List<String> current = next;
        hasNext = checkNext();
        return current;
    }
}
```

I know this is bad code, I see even now things that could be instantly refactored (`if(null != matchWord || startNext != null) {`...), don't hate me.

Answer (score 0):

You could store list with match in a field, compare it with null in `hasNext`, and return value in `next`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `list with match`?